# Xcode 7 with El Capitan text editor display broken sometimes after scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, text-editor, osx-elcapitan

The issue has been there since the El Capitan update (half year ago?), and from time to time after scrolling the text editor shows like this:
[image]

Anyone faced similar issues and have a fix? Thanks a lot!
I'm currently on Xcode 7.3.1 with Macbook Pro 13" with OS X El Capitan 10.11.4

Comment: Did you try fresh installation of both EL Capitan and xcode?

Comment: Found out it's a Xvim caused issue - thanks @Aslam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a Xvim caused issue: https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim/issues/882

It is fixed in Xvim developer branch. I'll leave this question here for other people who experience the same issue and look for an answer in SO.